# How to get last six month of data from DB using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have tried many different queries that already given here, but it also shows previous year data, for example, if use this query

```
 Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0)
```

or

```
DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)
```

These will result in the last six months. In my case, I want to print the last six month data. But the problem is if there is a data with the same date and different in the year will also result with these query eg (the above query returns the result of '2018-03-27 10:04:52.537' and if there is a data with '2017-03-27 10:04:52.537' will also come with the result). Can anyone help me?

here is my query

```
DECLARE @date6MonthAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp) 
DECLARE @totalCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                           FROM   [PSA].[ProductionOrder] 
                           WHERE  CreatedDate >= @date6MonthAgo) 
DECLARE @openCount INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                          FROM   [PSA].[ProductionOrder] 
                          WHERE  DocumentStatusCode=7 
                          AND    CreatedDate >= @date6MonthAgo ) 

SELECT @date6MonthAgo, @totalCount, @openCount
```

Comment: You have not posted a complete functioning query. `SELECT DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)` does not return a date prior to `2017-03-27` so it must have something to do with your actual query. Maybe you have an `OR` in the wrong place

Comment: `DECLARE @date6MonthAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)
DECLARE @totalCount INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PSA].[ProductionOrder] WHERE CreatedDate >= @date6MonthAgo)
DECLARE @openCount INT=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PSA].[ProductionOrder] WHERE DocumentStatusCode=7 AND CreatedDate >= @date6MonthAgo )

SELECT @date6MonthAgo,@totalCount,@openCount`

Comment: here i posted my query. @Nick.McDermaid im not mean that query will result 2017-03-27 10:04:52.537. im trying to say the issue,

Comment: Please edit the original question and put it in there.

Comment: your query will not return data with `CreatedDate` older than 6 month. You can do a `SELECT * FROM [PSA].[ProductionOrder] WHERE  CreatedDate >= @date6MonthAgo` to verify the result

Comment: @dhanildinesan Can you provide some sample data from `ProductionOrder` table?

Comment: i want the count. now its not resulting the proper count, the problem is with the year

Comment: What is the column TYPE for the CreatedDate?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale table datas are too long i cant do that sorry

Comment: @donPablo datetime

Comment: problem is *not* with the year. Something else going on here. The fact you are using `m,-6` does not mean *subtract 6 months from any year*, it means *subtract 6 months from this date* and it returns another date. So take another look, as you are focused on the wrong thing.

Comment: @dhanildinesan My concern is related to `CreatedDate` column

Comment: Good question @donPablo. Please give us the data type for createddate.

Comment: ok thank you @TomC

Comment: these are datas in CreatedDate       2018-09-24 11:05:52.727
2018-09-18 11:38:49.160
2018-09-18 11:35:46.997
2018-09-27 09:35:41.537 @PrashantPimpale

Comment: That looks like a date, but it could be text data formatted this way - cant tell. Need to look at the actual table definition to see the data type.  However I see that you have got an answer so hopefully you are all sorted.

Comment: None of your queries return dates, so what makes you think it's returning these incorrect dates?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Its not about returning dates, its about the count.

Comment: So based on the counts what makes you think it’s including incorrect dates? You haven’t yet inspected the dates to see if it is incorrectly including them, or whether you are just making an incorrect assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this, after putting in the correct IDcolumn, just to verify for yourself the dates that are being returned

```
DECLARE @date6MonthAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp); 
SELECT  @date6MonthAgo;

SELECT CreatedDate, keycolumnID
FROM   [PSA].[ProductionOrder] 
WHERE  DocumentStatusCode=7 
AND    CreatedDate >= @date6MonthAgo 
ORDER BY CreatedDate;
```

Comment: what do you see for the oldest date when you run this?

Comment: now i get proper result.. let me check my query again. thank you brother @donPablo

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for find the last 6 month data from current date,

```
DECLARE @fromdate as datetime, @todate as datetime

set @fromdate = (select DATEADD(month, -6, getdate()))
set @todate = getdate()

SELECT CreatedDate, keycolumnID
FROM   [PSA].[ProductionOrder] 
WHERE  DocumentStatusCode=7 
AND    cast(CreatedDate as date) between  cast(@fromdate as date) and  cast(@todate as date)
ORDER BY CreatedDate;
```

If you want find last 6 month date from a specific date, so you can set that date in @fromdate and @todate parameters like this,

```
set @fromdate = (select DATEADD(month, -6, @Yourdate))
set @todate = @Yourdate
```